# Jersey 2 POST and PUT parameter is null

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have a problem with my jersey rest service when method is PUT or POST. The problem is that parameter is null. I test with angularjs and jersey-test-framework with same result, the parameter is null.

I thought the problem was due to the header "Content-Type" but I add this in my test with the same result.

**Jersey version**: 2.14

**Jersey modules**: jersey-container-servlet, jersey-spring3, jersey-media-json-jackson

My application config and object mapper:

```
public class CustomObjectMapper implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

   final ObjectMapper defaultObjectMapper;

   public CustomObjectMapper() {
      defaultObjectMapper = createDefaultMapper();
   }

   @Override
   public ObjectMapper getContext(final Class<?> type) {
      return defaultObjectMapper;
   }

   private static ObjectMapper createDefaultMapper() {
      final ObjectMapper result = new ObjectMapper();

      return result;
   }

}

@ApplicationPath("/")
public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig {

   public ApplicationConfig() {
      packages("es.fjtorres.cpFacturas.server.api.impl",
            "es.fjtorres.cpFacturas.server.config",
            "es.fjtorres.cpFacturas.server.filter",
            "com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs");

      property(
           "jersey.config.beanValidation.enableOutputValidationErrorEntity.server",
            true);

      register(CustomObjectMapper.class);
      register(JacksonFeature.class);
   }
}
```

My resource partial code:

```
@Named
@Path(CUSTOMERS_PATH)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class CustomerResourceImpl extends AbstractResource implements
      ICustomerResource 

   ...

   @Override
   @POST
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public Response add(final CustomerDto pDto) {
      try {
         getService().add(pDto);
      } catch (final ValidationException ve) {
         badRequest(ve.getErrors());
      }

      return Response.ok().build();
   }

}
```

My unit test:

```
@Test
public void addTest() {
    final Response response = target(NameTokens.CUSTOMERS_PATH).request()
            .header("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .post(Entity.entity(new CustomerDto(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

    Assert.assertNotNull(response, "Response cannot be null");
    Assert.assertEquals(response.getStatus(), Status.OK.getStatusCode(),
            "Response status code isn't ok");
}
```

Comment: Please show us your CustomerDto provider (the MessageBodyReader, that converts the posted json into a CustomerDto instance)

Comment: I don't have provider for customerdto, I think that this job is for jersey-media-json-jackson. I have two paths with GET method and return customerdto information in json correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem are the CORS filters, I review the filters code to solve the problem with POST and PUT requests. I have two CORS filter (one to request and other for response) with the following code.

```
@Provider
public class CorsRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

   @Override
   public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext)
         throws IOException {
      if (requestContext.getRequest().getMethod().equals(HttpMethod.OPTIONS)) {
         requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build());
      }
   }
}

@Provider
public class CorsResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext,
            final ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
        final MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = responseContext.getHeaders();

        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token");
    }

}
```